# Global streamreader and streamwriter? How to properly use "using"

Tags: c#, using, streamreader, streamwriter

Coming from C/C++, I am used to use pointers to handle most of my operations however I understand the importance of using "using" statement when streamreader/streamwriter is used.

However I am facing a peculiar issue in the sense that I have one method/function that opens/declares the streamreader/streamwriter and I have another method/function to actually read/write to the stream. But the "using" statement is only local so there is no way for me to properly use the "using" statement in the function that does the actual reading/writing. The streamreader/streamwrite are defined in the class definition that is accessible to the class itself only. the two methods are both class functions.

This might be a very newbie question but I couldnt find anything useful online. Thank you.

Comment: This is why StreamReader/Writer also have a Close() method.

Comment: Implement `IDisposable` and let the comsumer of your class use `using`

Comment: Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you need to return `IDisposable` object outside of the scope where it is created, you can do so, provided that some other code somewhere calls `.Dispose()` on it once it is no longer used.

However, for a more complete answer, you should post some code.  A refactor may be possible to help avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: I have StreamWriter writename defined in the class definition and then I have one function: private bool Create_Writer(String filename, ref StreamWriter writername) { writename = new StreamWriter(filename, false); } then i have another function called : Private void Write_stuff() { if(writename!=null) { //write stuff } } So what is the correct way of disposing the object if I only write stuff to the file after a user clicks a button which routes to an event handler User_Click_Button that calls Write_stuff?

Comment: In addition, the class is automatically destroyed upon the exit of a particular "screen", as part of the class, will the streamwriter and reader be disposed as well upon class destruction? Thanks

Comment: Nope, if disposable object is member of the class, destroying on destructor is a bit too late (can't guarantee when it'll get called), so that means that your class that references your disposable also has to be marked `IDisposable`.

Comment: I get it. What if I know exactly when to call Dispose() for the streamreaders and streamwriters, will that be OK? (I know that once I complete writing, i can dispose those items.)

Comment: @user2584960 Yes, you're not required to use `using`.  You can certainly call `Dispose()` yourself.  `using` just makes it easier, and using makes it a guarantee that dispose will get called (even if exception occurs and stack is unwound).  There are certainly valid cases when you need to do it yourself.  One simple example is `SqlConnection.CreateCommand()` where Microsoft is creating disposable `SqlCommand` instance and returning to caller (and thus is not done with `using`), and caller is responsible for calling dispose (which caller can do using `using` or directly via `Dispose()`)

Answer (score 1):

`using() { ... }` is just a convenient way of calling `.Dispose()` at the end of your scope.
You don't always have to use `using() { ... }`.  You might want to handle the lifetime of your object explicitly.

Comment: I have 
StreamWriter writename defined in the class definition and then I have one function:

private bool Create_Writer(String filename, ref StreamWriter writername)
{
  writename = new StreamWriter(filename, false);
} 

then i have another function called :

Private void Write_stuff()
{
if(writename!=null)
{
//write stuff
}
}


So what is the correct way of disposing the object if I only write stuff to the file after a user clicks a button which routes to an event handler User_Click_Button that calls Write_stuff?  Thanks

Comment: sorry, i am not good at using the formatting feature... @AlfredBr

Comment: @user2584960 Question, why are you creating write far well in advance of actually using it?  Can you defer creation of writer until call to User_Click_Button?

Comment: It is because I am porting a legacy software over that is in C. In legacy program, The user will select an option and the file descriptor is created and assigned, it then displays information to the user. The user then confirms and then the writer proceeds to write. I dont seem to find a way to get around it since the information must be displayed right after the user selects an option. And the information is based on the outcome of the file descriptor creation result.